# How to get adjacency list of a DAG as a type "dict" using Networkx package?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs

**My attempts:** I have created a DiGraph using *networkx* package and two edges were added. Then tried to obtain adjacency list using `G.adj`. Then I received the adjacency list in the type of *AdjacencyView*. I have tried changing the output by `list(G.adj)` but it did not give me the expected result.

```
G =nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([('1','2'),('2','3')])

G.adj
Out[65]: AdjacencyView({'1': {'2': {}}, '2': {'3': {}}, '3': {}})

list(G.adj)
Out[66]: ['1', '2', '3']
```

Then I tried using `dict(G.adj)` then I received the expected output partially but type *AtlasView* was visible.

```
dict(G.adj)
Out[70]: {'1': AtlasView({'2': {}}), '2': AtlasView({'3': {}}), '3': AtlasView({})}
```

**What I'm looking for:** I'm looking for just to output the adjacency list as a type *dict* as shown below. May I know how to convert *AdjacencyView* type output to a type of *dict* ? Thank you!

```
{'1': {'2': {}}, '2': {'3': {}}, '3': {}}
Out[71]: {'1': {'2': {}}, '2': {'3': {}}, '3': {}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [adjacency](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.adjacency.html):

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('1','2'),('2','3')])    
print({k: v for k, v in G.adjacency()})
```

*Output*:

```
{'1': {'2': {}}, '2': {'3': {}}, '3': {}}
```